# Focusing on an input and change the label style

Tags: html, css

I want to change `label` color when focusing on `.input`

```
<label>This is a label</label>
<input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>
```

Definetely selecting `.input:focus + label` won't work because `label` goes first. So, I've tried to do it as `label + .input:focus` but I know it doesn't work either.

```css
.search {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: gray;
}


/* This is what I want to modify */

.input:focus+label {
  color: #f00;
}

.input https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65970655/edit#{
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 7.5px 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background: transparent;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2> This what I want to modify</h2>
<label>This is a label</label>
<input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder" />

<br>

<h2>Changing the order does work </h2>
<input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder" />
<label>This is a label</label>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to do this, you'll just need to move your input inside of your label:

```css
label:focus-within {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<label>
  This is a label
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder" />
</label>
```

Comment: Great Hunter, this is what I was looking for, it was just a matter of placing the element within the label and apply that selector, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**If you are able to edit the HTML:**

Put the label after the input and do:

CSS:

```
.input:focus ~ label {
  color:orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form_field">
   <input class="input" type="text" name="name" />
   <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Also view @Hunter McMillen answer because this is a nicer way to do it if you can access the HTML, you won't need the for attribute on the label then.

**If you can't alter the HTML for any reason use JavaScript:**

So we need to use JavaScript if you can't change the order of HTML.

First we can create a function to toggle a class on the previous sibling using `previousElementSibling` on the `e.target` when focused (we will use an event listener).

The blur event will happen when "un focused".

```js
// get the input in a variable for better readability
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.input');


// create a function which takes an event, so we can access the target
// and get its previous sibling (in our case the label).
const toggleSiblingClass = e => {
   // get the previous sibling of the event target (the input)
   const label = e.target.previousElementSibling;
   
   // toggle the class .focus on it, which we've assigned color:orange in css
   label.classList.toggle('focus');
}

input.forEach(el => {
   // on focus call the toggleSiblingClass function
   el.addEventListener('focus', toggleSiblingClass);
   
   // on focus out call the function again to toggle class off
   el.addEventListener('blur', toggleSiblingClass);
})
```

```css
label.focus {
  color:orange;
}

label {
display:block;
}

input {
margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
  <label>This is a label</label>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>

  <label>This is a label</label>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>

  <label>This is a label</label>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>

  <label>This is a label</label>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>

  <label>This is a label</label>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Placeholder"/>
```

Comment: Wow this is a good answer, in JavaScript we can do thing more simple and with more features! I was looking to do it without JavaScript because the project doesn't require it, but I'll make sure to apply it on other projects